# Как в ASP.NET vNext создать сессию?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Создал форму во *View* с полями *Имя* и *Фамилия*, сделал валидацию (синхронную пока), и, если пользователь ввел корректные данные, то перенаправляет его на другой *View*.

Как сделать сессию (если правильно выражаюсь), чтобы пользователь, когда случайно закрыл сайт, смог сразу попасть на второй *View* (чтобы было перенаправление) и чтобы сессия длилась только 20 минут.

Мне кажется, это как-то будет связанно с *Cookies*, и проверка будет по *IP*, с которого заходили на сайт, но интересно: сессия будет запоминаться в *БД*?

Comment: От сессий лучше воздержаться и лучше послать лишний запрос в базу заполнил ли юзер данные из первого вью или нет.

Comment: Но хочется проверить если заходил пользователь который уже ввел данные в форму то сделать редирект в 2 View. Cookies помогут но не знаю как реализовать работу с ними.

Comment: Где вы сохраняете данные из первого вью? Почему бы там и не проверить?

Comment: Пока данные лежат в модели но сделаю потом сохранение в БД и например будет каждому пользователю сгенерироваться id и сохранится в БД и еще ip с которого зашел на сайт(чтобы сделать проверку) и первый view припишет в кукис пользователя id и когда истечет этот кукис. Но нужен просто пример работы с этими Cookie или с сессиями.

Comment: То что вы делаете это делает авторизация пользователя, если он входит через формс авторизацию или через авторизацию социальных сетей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В vNext механизим сессий поменялся по сравнению с ASP.NET. Теперь сессии включаются с использованием middleware [Microsoft.AspNet.Session](https://github.com/aspnet/Session) (nuget: [Microsoft.AspNet.Session](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Session/))

Суть механизма осталась той же - при создании сессии пользователю устанавливается cookie с session id, где-то на сервере по этому id хранятся данные сессии. В вашем случае - это флаг, дошел ли пользователь до второго шага и, скорее всего, данные первого шага.

Осторожнее при установке - сейчас beta4 (шаблон в студии) и (beta5 последняя версия) не слишком совместимы - лучше явно указывайте версию при подключении:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Session -Version 1.0.0-beta4 -Pre
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions -Version 1.0.0-beta4 -Pre
```

Пакет Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions нужен для добавления методов расширения вида `GetInt`/`SetInt` к `context.Session`.

после установки включаете сессии в `Startup.cs/Configure`:

```
app.UseSession();
```

и там же настраиваете сессию и хранилище:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // регистрирует стандартную реализацию IDistributedCache - в памяти
    services.AddCaching();

    services.AddSession(o =>
    {
        o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    });

    //...
}
```

Используете в контроллере как:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
// ...

// имена методов меняются от версии к версии
// см. методы их Microsoft.AspNet.Http.SessionCollectionExtensions;
// после заполнения первого
this.Context.Session.SetString("firstname", "Ivan");
this.Context.Session.SetInt("some_int", 42); // SetInt32 в beta5

// в другом действии при следующем заходе
string firstName = this.Context.Session.GetString("firstname");
int? someInt = this.Context.Session.GetInt("some_int"); // GetInt32 в beta5
```

Новый механизм сессий использует `IDistributedCache`, так что выбор места для сессий сводится к выбору реализации. По умолчанию - `.AddCaching()` - хранение в памяти. Кроме него можно попробовать хранение в Redis или SQL Server:

```
services.AddTransient<IDistributedCache, RedisCache>();

services.AddSqlServerCache(o =>
{
    o.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=ASPNET5SessionState;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    o.TableName = "Sessions";
});
```

Сам пакет и пакета и пример к нему есть на github, так что при любых вопросов проще посмотреть [прямо в код](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/samples/SessionSample/Startup.cs).